# Jumping, moving, and gravity in my 2D javascript game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having lots of issues with my gravity and jumping. My code doesn't execute how I want it to, and I've been messing around with it for a while. The jumping is bugging and the moving isn't as smooth as I want it. I want my gravity to work while i'm still jumping, so I set it to zero, but it just doesn't look natural. Here's my code. I hope someone can help

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = 800
canvas.height = 600

class Main {
    constructor(x, y, w, h) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.w = w
        this.h = h
        this.lives = 3;
        this.speedX = 0;
        this.speedY = 0;
        this.gravity = 0.03;
        this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        this.dx = 0;
        this.dy = 0;
    }

    draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        ctx.fill()
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    newPos() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;   
    }

    update() {

        if(this.y >= canvas.height - 50) {
            this.y = canvas.height - 50
        }

        if (controller1.up) {this.dy -= 2, this.gravity = 0.01}; 
        if (controller1.right) {this.dx += 0.5};
        if (controller1.left) {this.dx -= 0.5};
        this.x += this.dx;  
        this.y += this.dy;
        this.dx *= 0.9;
        this.dy *= 0.9;
        this.draw();
    }
}

class Controller {
    constructor() {
      this.up = false;
      this.right = false;
      this.down = false;
      this.left = false;
      
      let keyEvent = (e) => {
        if (e.code == "KeyW" || e.code == "ArrowUp") {this.up = e.type == 'keydown'};
        if (e.code == "KeyD" || e.code == "ArrowRight") {this.right = e.type == 'keydown'};
        if (e.code == "KeyA" || e.code == "ArrowLeft") {this.left = e.type == 'keydown'};
        
      }
      addEventListener('keydown', keyEvent);
      addEventListener('keyup', keyEvent);
      addEventListener('mousemove', keyEvent)
      }
  }

let main1 = new Main(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 50, 50)
let controller1 = new Controller();

function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    main1.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

function updatePos() {
    main1.newPos();
}

animate()
setInterval(updatePos, 10)
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remember that SO is not here to "help fix your code", it's here to "help resolve one (and only one) specific issue your code has". Determine what part is the most important, then turn your code into a [mcve] that focusses on that issue, and then you have something that makes sense to post to SO. And, of course, the whole MCVE exercise is really for you, not for us: by forcing yourself to reduce your code to focussed, individual things, you almost always find what's going wrong on your own, obviating the need to even post a question (here, or anywhere else).

Comment: Also note that the snippet button really is _for runnable snippets only_ and your code very much is not that: just use normal code blocks if what you're showing is just code, rather than something that will actually meaningfully run when clicking the "run code snippet" button.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I added the snippet, OP posted just the code. In this case where the question is about the execution of the code, it is easier to see the problem with something that is runnable.

Comment: @ChrisG Then please fix that runnable: you don't get a full document to work with, that runnable only gets about 150px of height before things turn into scrollbar nonsense.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes the code is sized larger than the frame, but there is a full screen option on SO for a reason. I left the original code unmodified intentionally as it relates to the question. Arbitrarily modifying submitted code could affect the desired outcome or circumvent the question entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Great effort thus far. Game dev can be a bit tricky in the beginning to get things look and feel like you want it. I modified your main class a bit and made the jump a bit smoother. You are not using dt (delta time) which makes it easier to handle jumping with gravity (not the only way to do it). And remember that gravity is a constant, if you set it to 0 it means we have nothing to pull the player back onto the ground. Gravity is always there and when we jump we counter it for a second or two.

If you want to read some more about this you can google on "2D game physics + jumping" or something similar. Here are some links that I found on the topic.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32631/easy-way-to-do-gravity-in-a-simple-game
https://www.gamedev.net/tutorials/_/technical/math-and-physics/a-verlet-based-approach-for-2d-game-physics-r2714/
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/60008/smooth-jumping-in-2d-platformers

I recommend the Game Development community on Stack Overflow for these questions too https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Feel free to ask if you have further questions

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = 600
canvas.height = 200

let time; // Current time
let prevTime = Date.now(); // Store previous time
let isGrounded; // Check if player is on the ground

class Main {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.lives = 3;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.gravity = .01;
    // this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.jumpSpeed = -1.5; // How fast to jump upwards
    this.dx = 0;
    this.dy = 0;
}
  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  newPos() {
    this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
    this.x += this.speedX;
  }

  update() {
    // Calculate how much time has passed since last update
    time = Date.now();
    const deltaTime = time - prevTime;

    // Update y-position based speed in y-direction
    // If we jump this.speed will be set to this.jumpSpeed
    this.y += this.speedY * deltaTime;
    // Gravity should always affect the player!
    // The ground check will make sure we don't fall through the floor
    this.y += this.gravity * deltaTime;
    // Make sure to reduce our player's speed in y by gravity!
    this.speedY += this.gravity * deltaTime;

    // Only allow the player to jump if he is on the ground
    if (controller1.up && isGrounded) {
      // Set the player y-speed to jump speed
      this.speedY = this.jumpSpeed;
    };

    if (controller1.right) {this.dx += 0.5};
    if (controller1.left) {this.dx -= 0.5};
    
    this.x += this.dx;
    // this.y += this.dy;
    this.dx *= 0.9;
    this.dy *= 0.9;

    // Ground check
    if(this.y >= canvas.height - 50) {
      this.y = canvas.height - 50;
      isGrounded = true;
    } else {
      isGrounded = false;
    }

    this.draw();
    
    // Store the current time to use for calculation in next update
    prevTime = Date.now();
  }

}

class Controller {
  constructor() {
    this.up = false;
    this.right = false;
    this.down = false;
    this.left = false;

    let keyEvent = (e) => {
      if (e.code == "KeyW" || e.code == "ArrowUp") {this.up = e.type == 'keydown'};
      if (e.code == "KeyD" || e.code == "ArrowRight") {this.right = e.type == 'keydown'};
      if (e.code == "KeyA" || e.code == "ArrowLeft") {this.left = e.type == 'keydown'};
    }

    addEventListener('keydown', keyEvent);
    addEventListener('keyup', keyEvent);
    addEventListener('mousemove', keyEvent)
  }
}

let main1 = new Main(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 50, 50)
let controller1 = new Controller();

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  main1.update();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

function updatePos() {
  main1.newPos();
}

animate()
setInterval(updatePos, 10)
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    canvas {
      background-color: azure;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set your gravity to a global variable to start. This will allow all objects you create to reference the same gravity value. Depending on how much gravity you set will change how much negative value you give your jump command. I also add a separate `canvasCollision()` function in the class for this example.

Also keep in mind I changed the canvas size for this example.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 300;
const gravity = 2;

class Main {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.lives = 3;
    this.speedX = 0.5;
    this.speedY = 35;
    this.jumping = false;
    this.vx = 0;
    this.vy = 0;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  canvasCollision() {
    if (this.x <= 0) this.x = 0;
    if (this.y <= 0) this.y = 0;
    if (this.x + this.w >= canvas.width) this.x = canvas.width - this.w;
    if (this.y + this.h >= canvas.height) {
      this.y = canvas.height - this.h;
      this.vy = 0;
      this.jumping = false;
    }
  }
  update() {
    if (controller1.left) this.vx -= this.speedX;
    if (controller1.up && !this.jumping) {
      this.vy -= this.speedY;
      this.jumping = true;
    }
    if (controller1.right) this.vx += this.speedX;
    this.vy += gravity;
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;
    this.vx *= 0.9;
    this.vy *= 0.9;
    this.canvasCollision();
  }
}

class Controller {
  constructor() {
    this.up = false;
    this.right = false;
    this.down = false;
    this.left = false;

    let keyEvent = (e) => {
      if (e.code == "KeyW" || e.code == "ArrowUp") {
        this.up = e.type == "keydown";
      }
      if (e.code == "KeyD" || e.code == "ArrowRight") {
        this.right = e.type == "keydown";
      }
      if (e.code == "KeyA" || e.code == "ArrowLeft") {
        this.left = e.type == "keydown";
      }
    };
    addEventListener("keydown", keyEvent);
    addEventListener("keyup", keyEvent);
    addEventListener("mousemove", keyEvent);
  }
}

let main1 = new Main(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 50, 50);
let controller1 = new Controller();

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  main1.update();
  main1.draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```html
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```